# Add indentifiers to dataframe index

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have `two` `dataframe` as follows:

```
df1:
                 
      column1
    0 aaa
    1 aaa
    2 aaa
    3 aaa

df2:
      column1
    0 aaa
    1 aaa
    2 aaa
    3 aaa
```

I want to `concat` them but I want to know which value comes from which `dataframe`

So I want a `dataframe` like

```
df1:
                 
        Index    column1
    0   0_df1      aaa
    1   1_df1      aaa
    2   2_df1      aaa
    3   3_df1      aaa
    4   4_df2      aaa
    5   5_df2      aaa
    6   6_df2      aaa
```

I know how to make the index `column` but I cannot add "identifier" to its values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a column for each dataframe with the name of the dataframe, then add the index to this column after concatenation:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']})
df1['Index'] = 'df1'
df2['Index'] = 'df2'

cat = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
cat['Index'] = cat.index.astype(str) + '_' + cat['Index'] # add the index
cat = cat[['Index', 'column1']] # reorder the columns
```

```
Index   column1
0   0_df1   aaa
1   1_df1   aaa
2   2_df1   aaa
3   3_df1   aaa
4   4_df2   aaa
5   5_df2   aaa
6   6_df2   aaa
7   7_df2   aaa
```

Comment: can i have the INDEX on the left of column1?

Comment: `cat = cat[['Index', 'column1']]`

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution I can think of:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['aaa','aaa','aaa','aaa']})

df1["Index"] = df1.index.astype(str) + '_df1'
df2["Index"] = df2.index.astype(str) + '_df2'

pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

The output:

```
column1  Index
0     aaa  0_df1
1     aaa  1_df1
2     aaa  2_df1
3     aaa  3_df1
4     aaa  0_df2
5     aaa  1_df2
6     aaa  2_df2
7     aaa  3_df2
```

You can also create multi-index keys with concat by:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['df1','df2'])
```

which gives:

```
      column1
df1 0     aaa
    1     aaa
    2     aaa
    3     aaa
df2 0     aaa
    1     aaa
    2     aaa
    3     aaa
```